# C# Point to dynamically loading assemblies

Tags: c#, assemblies

What's the point of dynamically loading an assembly? Isn't it just way simpler to just reference it in your solution/project, saving you all the calls to `Assembly.*Load*` functions?

Update: Is it useful outside of plugins? What about exclusively in web development, what uses would I find there for dynamically loading an assembly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dynamically loading an assembly is useful for anything requiring execution of external code that might not even *exist* when the hosting program is developed.

For instance, any plug-in system will have to use that feature.

Comment: Dynamically loading assemblies also allows the use of AppDomains, which allow you to restrict the permissions granted to the assembly by placing it in a more restrictive zone.

Answer (score 1):

What if you want to make it possible to write plugins for your application, which get loaded at runtime and you don't have that project at compiletime?

Answer (score 1):

You may not have that assembly when you compile your code, think of plugins for instance. You can't compile with a reference to them. Other reason is generating and compiling code and then loadin that Advanced stuff but real use.

GJ